# SMSLib doesn't receive sms [java edition]

Tags: java, sms, nokia, gsm, smslib

i am trying to use my mobile phone as GSM modem.i use SMSLib for sending and receiving SMS with this modem.
the problem is that when my phone(GSM modem) receive a sms i don't notify with SMSLib.but the code overall is good for example that notifies me when GSM modem receive a call.
my code has not any bug because i only use SMSLib example code for receiving message.
the SMSLib example code is :

```
public class TestSinaRec
{
    public void doIt() throws Exception
    {
        // Define a list which will hold the read messages.
        List<InboundMessage> msgList;
        // Create the notification callback method for inbound & status report
        // messages.
        InboundNotification inboundNotification = new InboundNotification();
        // Create the notification callback method for inbound voice calls.
        CallNotification callNotification = new CallNotification();
        //Create the notification callback method for gateway statuses.
        GatewayStatusNotification statusNotification = new GatewayStatusNotification();
        OrphanedMessageNotification orphanedMessageNotification = new OrphanedMessageNotification();
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Example: Read messages from a serial gsm modem.");
            System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
            System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
            // Create the Gateway representing the serial GSM modem.
            SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com4", "COM4", 115200, "Nokia", " 6303i");
            // Set the modem protocol to PDU (alternative is TEXT). PDU is the default, anyway...
            gateway.setProtocol(Protocols.PDU);
            // Do we want the Gateway to be used for Inbound messages?
            gateway.setInbound(true);
            // Do we want the Gateway to be used for Outbound messages?
            gateway.setOutbound(true);
            // Let SMSLib know which is the SIM PIN.
            gateway.setSimPin("0444");
            // Set up the notification methods.
            Service.getInstance().setInboundMessageNotification(inboundNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setCallNotification(callNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setGatewayStatusNotification(statusNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setOrphanedMessageNotification(orphanedMessageNotification);
            // Add the Gateway to the Service object.
            Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
            // Similarly, you may define as many Gateway objects, representing
            // various GSM modems, add them in the Service object and control all of them.
            // Start! (i.e. connect to all defined Gateways)
            Service.getInstance().startService();
            // Printout some general information about the modem.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Modem Information:");
            System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
            System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
            System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
            System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
            System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
            System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
            System.out.println();
            // In case you work with encrypted messages, its a good time to declare your keys.
            // Create a new AES Key with a known key value. 
            // Register it in KeyManager in order to keep it active. SMSLib will then automatically
            // encrypt / decrypt all messages send to / received from this number.
            //Service.getInstance().getKeyManager().registerKey("+306948494037", new AESKey(new SecretKeySpec("0011223344556677".getBytes(), "AES")));
            // Read Messages. The reading is done via the Service object and
            // affects all Gateway objects defined. This can also be more directed to a specific
            // Gateway - look the JavaDocs for information on the Service method calls.
            msgList = new ArrayList<InboundMessage>();
            Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, MessageClasses.ALL);
            for (InboundMessage msg : msgList)
                System.out.println(msg);
            // Sleep now. Emulate real world situation and give a chance to the notifications
            // methods to be called in the event of message or voice call reception.
            System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to stop service.");
            System.in.read();
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            Service.getInstance().stopService();
        }
    }

    public class InboundNotification implements IInboundMessageNotification
    {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, MessageTypes msgType, InboundMessage msg)
        {
            if (msgType == MessageTypes.INBOUND) System.out.println(">>> New Inbound message detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            else if (msgType == MessageTypes.STATUSREPORT) System.out.println(">>> New Inbound Status Report message detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

    public class CallNotification implements ICallNotification
    {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, String callerId)
        {
            System.out.println(">>> New call detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId() + " : " + callerId);
        }
    }

    public class GatewayStatusNotification implements IGatewayStatusNotification
    {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, GatewayStatuses oldStatus, GatewayStatuses newStatus)
        {
            System.out.println(">>> Gateway Status change for " + gateway.getGatewayId() + ", OLD: " + oldStatus + " -> NEW: " + newStatus);
        }
    }

    public class OrphanedMessageNotification implements IOrphanedMessageNotification
    {
        public boolean process(AGateway gateway, InboundMessage msg)
        {
            System.out.println(">>> Orphaned message part detected from " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
            // Since we are just testing, return FALSE and keep the orphaned message part.
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestSinaRec app = new TestSinaRec();
        try
        {
            app.doIt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

program output is for example :

> Gateway Status change for modem.com4, OLD: STOPPED -> NEW: STARTING
>    Gateway Status change for modem.com4, OLD: STARTING -> NEW: STARTED
>
> Modem Information:   Manufacturer: Nokia   Model: Nokia 6303i classic 
>   Serial No: 355382041051833   SIM IMSI: ** MASKED **   Signal Level:
>   -57 dBm   Battery Level: 91%
>
> Now Sleeping - Hit  to stop service.
>   New call detected from Gateway: modem.com4 : +989111007483
>   New call detected from Gateway: modem.com4 : +989111007483

when i searched for this issue i found this :

> The correct operation of this method depends on the unsolicited modem
>   indications and on the correct operation of the CNMI command. If you
>   see that you are failing to receive messages using a callback method,
>   probably the modem indications have not been setup correctly.

so i changed my phone(my GSM modem) with Nokia 6303i rather than Nokia 5200 that i used first but the problem didn't solve.
so now i really don't know the problem will solve with choosing another phones ?! or i should search for a better and more reasonable solution.

thank you for any bit of help for solving this problem.

Comment: no a java desktop program that plugged with a phone as GSM modem.but of you asked about the platform of GSM modem it is java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my phone.Smslib doesn't work in listening sms for a variety of phones(including smartphones,most of Nokia phones,etc.).I didn't check but probably this problem will be solved if you use a dedicated GSM modem(like huawei GSM modems)

Answer (score 0):

Well the only thing I can think of is that you're starting the `Service` and **then** sending the SMS to the modem. Because of this, this line won't be called: `Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, MessageClasses.ALL);`. However, you should still get the notification that a new message has arrived at the modem.

Try implementing the `InboundNotification` to fetch the messages when it senses any new messages on the modem. Do this by overriding the `process()` method.

However, it might also be due to the fact that you're actually pressing `<Enter>` too soon. As the comment say; you have to wait go give the notifications method a chance to be called.

Sometimes it's just something as silly as that. Let me know if any of it helped or if I completely misunderstood your problem. I'm working on a multi-modem gateway myself, so I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

i had an issue with a GT-I9000 he received the inbound alert but couldn't fetch it the right sms object, i think this is a matter of the Storage Location,
i tried with another phone (Samsung GT-S5670 Android) of a friend of mine who had some messages stored on the SIM Card Memory, the smslibrary was notified and the ReadMessages Class logged all the messages.

so i think you need to find somehow to change storage location on the ReadMessages.java or find an compatible phone that can stores the sms to Sim Card instead of the phone memory.

hope this help.